# Why setting the command window height to 2 lines, avoid many cases of having to "press <Enter> to continue"?

Tags: vim

I found this on my `.vimrc`:

```
Set the command window height to 2 lines, to avoid many cases of having to
" "press <Enter> to continue"
set cmdheight=2
```

And this causes this extra space at the bottom of the page:
[image]

And if I set it to `set cmdheight=1`, then I got a smaller space:
[image]

I do not understand I need to `set cmdheight=2`. What are these `many cases of having to "press <Enter> to continue"`?

It seems nice to not have to keep pressing enter repeatedly (for whatever reason it is), but why I need to lose one (1) line of vertical space in the screen for that?

Comment: `many cases`: try setting `cmdheight` to 1 and running a command that for some reason adds a trailing newline to its output (as a test, `:echo "foobar\n"`, but many actual utilities do it). You'll get the prompt. There may be more possibilities, not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The press-enter prompt appears if the cmdline area is not big enough to display a text.

E.g. a plugin prints more lines then what `'cmdheight'` is set to. It even happens when `cmdheight=1`, but the line to be printed is longer than the width of the window.

```
:set cmdheight=1
:echomsg "foo" | echomsg "bar"
```

IMHO, setting `'cmdheight'` to 2 or higher is not worth it, because it simply looks ugly and steals space to work around a not too common press-enter prompt.

Rather plugins should take it into account and "flush" their messages via `:redraw`:

```
:echomsg "foo" | redraw | echomsg "bar"
```

Now, you'll only see the latter message, but still find the former one in the message history via `:messages`.

See `:h press-enter` for more information on this.